# KineticJS - Text metrics - how can I get position of text baseline?

Tags: php, html, canvas, fpdf, kineticjs

I'm using `KineticJS` to position text using draggable Kinetic.text and then export to `PDF` based on the height and width of the text on screen.

The pdf exporter I'm using (`fpdf`) measures the text from the baseline, however Kinetic seems to measure from top.

Any idea how I can either alter where it is measured from or get the value of the difference in either Kinetic or FPDF?

Comment: What have you tried?  What hasn't worked?  What research have you done to solve the problem?  Shouldn't you just be able to adjust the coordinates?  If you know the height of the text, you should be able to calculate the difference between the top and the baseline...

Comment: I mean the baseline being the line at the bottom of the letters, e.g without tails like the of a y. I have the total height but not to this line.

Comment: Assuming the text will always be one size, or a limited set of sizes, and in one font or a limited set of fonts, it's pretty trivial to *pre*-calculate that value.